# How to show default data when user clears input field in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using the jquery-ui-autocomplete plugin, but slightly tweaked it for giving an auto-load feel instead of auto-complete.
I am displaying the result in a div bellow the input field instead of a dropdown view for it.

I have set the minlength to 1 so that it doesnot change the default data in the div on clicking in the input box.

But once the user has typed something, and result is displayed in the div, now if the user clears the input field, it keeps showing the last search result. I want to display some default data here that is displayed on page load.
How can i do this?

code snippet:

```
$("#search-help").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term)
        , containsMatcherTitle = new RegExp(term, "i")
        , containsTitle = $.grep(data, function(value) {
            return containsMatcherTitle.test(value.value);
        });

        response((containsTitle.slice(0, 5));
    },
    focus: function( event, ui ) {

        return false;
    },
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {

            return false;
    },
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $("#MY_DIV ul").empty();
    }
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

    return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" + item.value + "</a><span>" + item.desc + "</span>" )
    .appendTo($('#MY_DIV ul'));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what format you want in the div, but you can create an event like the following:

```
$("#search-help").keyup(function( ) {
       if (!this.value) { 
              $('#MY_DIV').val("Default text");
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Mccannf that worked perfectly. How silly of me not to think of this, i was so engrossed with the auto-complete that i was looking for a solution within it only!